# Reading a TDMS file (LabVIEW) in the form of a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, labview

I am trying to read a relatively large TDMS file (LabVIEW) and I am having a few difficulties. The file is a 50x50 matrix (2500 elements) with two main variables: ROT in the vertical direction and L in the horizontal direction. If you open the TDMS with excel, it looks like this.
[image]

Also, the info data is here:
[image]

The code I have been using is below:

```
import numpy as np
pip install npTDMS
from nptdms import TdmsFile as td
import pandas as pd


def read_tdms(path):

    #Init of the dataframe 
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    tdms_file=TdmsFile.read("C:\\Users\\Venom\\Desktop\\Nueva carpeta\\1 S_05_V_P2_200430_140647.tdms")
    #Iteration loop over all groups
    for group in tdms_file.groups():
        group_name=group.name
        #Iteration loop over all channels
        for channels in group.channels():
            #Get data
            channel_name=channel.name
            properties=channel.properties
            print(f"properties of channels are: {properties}")
            print(f"channel name is: {channel_name}")
            data=channel[:]
        
            #Store the data into a Dataframe
            df[channel_name]=data
              
        
        else:
            pass
       
    return df
```

Apparently, I am not reading all channels and that’s why I get a dataframe with only the first channel (ROT) and the last channel (L49). You can check it here:
[image]

What can I do to get the full 50x50 matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is mistype in code, instead of "channels" indeed you use "channel" `(for channels in group.channels():)`.

But overall, you could convert whole group to dataframe:

```
for group in tdms_file.groups():
    df = tdms_file.object(group).as_dataframe()
```

Or you could even read complete file as dataframe:

```
df = tdms_file.as_dataframe()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was indeed a mistype in code. I changed it to "for channel in group.channels()" and it works.